# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, initialization, warnings

I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 255

char * decrypt(char *p, int key){
    char *tmp;
    for(int i = 0; p[i] != '\0'; i++){
        tmp[i] = p[i]-key;
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main(void){
    printf("Hallo Welt!");
    printf("%s\n", decrypt("ibmmp", 1));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I compile it with `gcc -Wall` i get the Warning `tmp could get uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized] tmp[i] = p[i]-key`(translated from german) and segmentation fault (core dumped) ./crypto when i run it

What is causing that error?

I know this quesion has been asked many times, but i could not fix this warning, because other people had different sourcecodes and i couldn't adapt it to my problem.

Comment: The pointer `tmp` doesn't point to anything. You need to allocate memory for it.

Comment: The value of `tmp`, since it is not initialized, is either 0 or unspecified. You then access memory at that value in the loop. Because this is exceedingly unlikely to be a valid pointer, the code crashes.

Comment: What does this have to do with compiler construction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate memory for `tmp` before using it. Make sure you null-terminate the string before returning it.

```
// Make the input a const string.
// char * decrypt(char *p, int key){
char * decrypt(char const* p, int key){
    char *tmp = malloc(strlen(p) + 1); // Allocate memory
    int i = 0;
    for( ; p[i] != '\0'; i++){
        tmp[i] = p[i]-key;
    }
    tmp[i] = '\0';                     // null terminate.
    return tmp;
}
```

Make sure you deallocate the memory. Just using

```
printf("%s\n", decrypt("ibmmp", 1));
```

will result in a memory leak.

```
int main(void){
    printf("Hallo Welt!");
    char* dec = decrypt("ibmmp", 1)
    printf("%s\n", dec);
    free(dec);                        // Deallocate memory.
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Ok, your example works,  but could you explain why a) i have to use a const char in the paramter and b) why do i have to nullterminate the string, isn't it nullterminatend automatically? Also your example can't work, because it's outside the for loop but uses the index i.

Comment: When you use `decrypt("ibmmp", 1)` and the argument type is not `char const*`, it is easy to make the mistake of modifying the argument in the function -- that will lead to undefined behavior since `"ibmmp"` is stored in read-only memory. If you use `char const*` as argument type, the compiler will let you know if you accidentally try to modify the contents of the input argument. No, the string is not null terminated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate 'tmp' and then, keeping with good 'c' coding, check that the allocation was successful.  I assume you have MAX defined so you can set an upper-bound on the length of your string, so I use that below.  If MAX is intended to be the number of characters *without* a null, then you need to 'malloc(MAX +1)'.  If it is intended to include NULL, then just leave the code as defined below.  You also want to decide what to return on failure of the malloc.  I return NULL, but you may want to do something different depending on your needs.

Also be aware, that this function is returning allocated memory, so someone needs to free it so you aren't leaking memory.

```
char * decrypt(char *p, int key){
    char *tmp;
    tmp = (char *) malloc(MAX);
    if(!tmp)
        return NULL;
    for(int i = 0; p[i] != '\0'; i++){
        tmp[i] = p[i]-key;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```